# ArcGIS Android and Retrofit

Tags: android, rest, arcgis-android

I'm working with Retrofit to connect my application with my API. Retrofit is using Jackson 2+, and ESRI is using Jackson 1.95+
So, I can't figure out how to solve this.

I have an application using Google Maps. I'm using Retrofit to connect my Android application with my REST service, so I can manage HTTP requests, send and receive information from my server hosted in AWS. I want to add a module, so the user can decide if he wants to use GoogleMaps or his own map imported from ArcGIS Online.

First, I spent hours trying to import these to IDEA 14, I was getting DEX problem (Library Repeated), looking deeply I found that Retrofit was using a newer version of Jackson, and ESRI is using an older one, so, I erase the ESRI Jackson Library and it seems to work, but when I run my app I'm getting a black screen on my MapView.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. It is highly unlikely the question in it's current form that it will excite an answer. Explain the project and how and why the application needs Jackson and retrofit.

Comment: @BradNesom edited

Comment: Good job. It sounds like you need to register the new jackson version in esri

Comment: How. I could try, but ArcGIS for Android itsnt Open Source